# In magento how to add flat price for shipping outside the default country

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, shipping, shipping-methods, free-shipping

I usually offer Free shipping over $10.

Currently I have a flat rate $1 shipping which becomes free over $10. I managed to do that using a shopping cart price rule.

Now there are customers who are ordering outside my default country & i cant ship the order for free or $1.I want to charge $50 as shipping price for customers outside USA.
How do i define a fixed price for orders that are outside my default country.

That price should only appear when the shipping country is outside USA.

In System>Configuration>General in magento backend, you define the default country & other allowed countries. 
There has to be a way to use these values for shipping prices.

If this is not inbuilt in magento then i am in for a surprise & heck of a time coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the Flat Rate shipping method you should use the **Table Rate shipping method** which will allow you to set the shipping rate by price vs destination among others.

With this method you need to create a CSV file with your table rate shipping pricing and upload it to the Magento admin panel.

The Magento User guide gives a pretty good set of instructions on it [here](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#shipping/table-rates.html).

It can be tedious creating a CSV file with all your destination countries, I've used [this web based tool](https://elgentos.nl/tablerates/) to generate one for me in the past.